# rails integration test pass with Itest but "rake test:integration" provides no output. no error though

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, integration-testing

When I run my integration tests individually using "ruby -Itest test/integration/mytest.rb", it works just fine.

When I try to run `rake test:integration` to run all my integration tests in one command, I have to wait a few seconds but I never get any output. No good result, no error.
If I run `rake --trace test:integration`, everything seems to be fine until the Execute test:integration (**which does not provide any output**).

Looks as though the integration folder was not found or was empty.

Any ideas?

Thanks
Christian

Comment: you may have to use `bundle exec rake test:integration` if you're using `Bundler`

Answer (score 1):

I've just spent 3 hours trying to figure this out, and get this: your test files must end with "_test.rb" otherwise they are skipped

Comment: This was the problem for me. I can't find any mention of this fact in the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html).